# How to make payment with different amount via In app purchase in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone

Please tell me How to make payment with different amount via In app purchase in iphone sdk?? as i am creating an application in which subscription charges deduced from a website and in the same way i want to make payment using my application and subscription amount change all the time.. as apple don't approve paypal for the same purpose. How to handle this problem??

can we use web services for deduction of charges and get response of success or failure from web services?

Comment: You can change the price of your in app purchase via iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For in-app purchases of app content, you're only allowed to use Apple's In-App Purchase system.  You're not allowed to use paypal or anything else from in the app.

The only way to set the price of an in-app purchase item is in iTunes Connect.  StoreKit (the API you use for in-app purchases) gets product prices from iTunes Connect, and there is no API for overriding the prices from within the app.

There's no public API (as far as I know) for changing the price in iTunes Connect, either.  Perhaps you can script the normal web browsing interface, or find code someone else has written that scripts it.  But the only way that Apple provides for changing the price of an in-app purchase is to log in to the iTunes Connect web site in a web browser.